# How to show duplicate data across several entities in a report

Tags: crystal-reports

I'm working on a report that retrieves information from several entities across our application.

The query I use retrieves all the employee numbers across diferent entities and displays them correctly, including duplicate numbers that exist across them, which is possible.

Example:

Entity 1 Employee John has number 1001

Entity 2 Employee Frank has number 1001

This is all correct and possible, but when I generate the report, it does not show all the numbers, as some of the duplicate ones are not shown.

If I were to use the example above when generating the report, only one of the numbers 1001 would show.

Is there a way to tell Crystal Reports to show everything including all the duplicate values?

Comment: There must be a reason why your report does not show the duplicate ones. Most likely it has a grouping by number/id, and what you're seeing is the fields in group header or footer.

Comment: I have a group by Number yes, but If I Preview the result in Crystal Reports, it shows the duplicates but if I open it on my application they do not show.

Answer (score 0):

Other main suspects are: Table joins and record selection formula.